# Remove rows with two conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have this following dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(Data = structure(c(1623888000, 1629158400, 1629158400
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Client = c("Client1", 
"Client1", "Client1"), Fund = c("Fund1", "Fund1", "Fund2"), Nature = c("Application", 
"Rescue", "Application"), Quantity = c(433.059697, 0, 171.546757
), Value = c(69800, -70305.67, 24875), `NAV Yesterday` = c(162.40991399996, 
162.40991399996, 145.044589000056), `NAV in Application Date` = c(161.178702344125, 
162.346370458944, 145.004198476337), `Var NAV` = c(0.00763879866215962, 
0.00039140721678275, 0.000278547270652531), `Var * Value` = c(533.188146618741, 
-27.5181466187465, 6.92886335748171), FinalValue = c(70333.1881466187, 
-70333.1881466187, 24881.9288633575), `Rentability WRONG` = c(0.0210345899274819, 
0.0210345899274819, 0.0210345899274819)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I need to do is:

If quantity = 0, then remove all rows with the same Fund name as that one, but remove only the rows that have Date < or = Date of the Quantity = 0 Fund

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did here is:

1. I grouped the data by `Fund`
2. **Arranged each group by `Data`**
3. Created a column `zero_point` that assigns `1` to the row where `Quantity == 0` and `NA` otherwise
4. Filled the fields in `zero_point` that come before the actual "zero point" with the same value.
5. filtered those rows out.

```
output <- df %>% 
  group_by(Fund) %>% 
  arrange(Data) %>% 
  mutate(zero_point = case_when(Quantity == 0 ~ 1)) %>%
  fill(zero_point, .direction = "up") %>% 
  filter(is.na(zero_point))
```

[image: Result]

*(On the condition that there is only one instance where Quantity is 0 per Fund group)*

Answer (score 1):

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter({
    #Row index where Quantity = 0
    inds = which(Quantity == 0)
    #Drop rows where Data value is less than Data value at Quantity = 0
    #and Fund is same as present at Quantity = 0.
    !(Data <= Data[inds] & Fund %in% Fund[inds])
  })
```

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the braces. It's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thought:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(Fund) %>%
  filter(!any(Quantity == 0) | Data <= Data[which.min(Quantity)])
# # A tibble: 3 x 12
# # Groups:   Fund [2]
#   Data                Client Fund  Nature Quantity   Value `NAV Yesterday` `NAV in Applica~ `Var NAV` `Var * Value` FinalValue `Rentability WR~
#   <dttm>              <chr>  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>            <dbl>
# 1 2021-06-17 00:00:00 Clien~ Fund1 Appli~     433.  69800             162.             161.  0.00764         533.       70333.           0.0210
# 2 2021-08-17 00:00:00 Clien~ Fund1 Rescue       0  -70306.            162.             162.  0.000391        -27.5     -70333.           0.0210
# 3 2021-08-17 00:00:00 Clien~ Fund2 Appli~     172.  24875             145.             145.  0.000279          6.93     24882.           0.0210
```

- I'm assuming you meant *"Data <= Data of the Quantity = 0 Fund"*, therefore using `Data` instead of `Date` (not found) or `NAV in Application Date`.
- This filters nothing in this sample data, I'm hoping the logic is correct.
- Testing for equality with floating-point (`numeric`) can be problematic at times (see [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518), [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004), and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). If you have some small near-zero numbers, then this will silently produce counter-intuitive results without warning or error. You might be more defensive to use something like:

  ```r
  df %>%
    group_by(Fund) %>%
    filter(all(abs(Quantity) > 0) | Data <= Data[which.min(Quantity)])
  ```

  or even

  ```r
  df %>%
    group_by(Fund) %>%
    filter(all(abs(Quantity) > 0) | 
             row_number() == which.min(Quantity) |
             Data < Data[which.min(Quantity)])
  ```

  While the latter is a bit paranoid (and double-calculates `which.min(.)`, it should not succumb to problems with equality tests.
- The only time this will fail is if `all(is.na(Quantity))`; that is, `which.min(c(NA,NA))` returns `integer(0)` which will cause an error in `dplyr::filter`. One might choose to add safeguard with something like `filter(any(!is.na(Quantity)) & (...))`.

Comment: That's very relevant but when I apply to my dataset, if I do 'group_by(Fund)' it erases the funds with Q=0 for all clients, and when I do 'group_by(Client)', it erases all clients who have rescued a fund completely (who have Q = 0). will try doing your solution inside a for loop which break clients into a list to see what I get

Comment: Sure, but ... are we supposed to infer based on the presence in your data that `Client` is a necessary grouping variable? Have you tried `group_by(Fund, Client)`? Your data is too sparse to be able to do much more than guess; if `Client` is relevant, than please include enough sample data so that that varies as well as `Fund`. And, unless it is applicable, we really don't need all of the other extraneous columns, please just include what is relevant to the question and your understanding of the data.

Comment: Yeah this was totally my fault, should have put a larger dataset to exemplify my problem.